# How to check if the input string is a valid Regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you check, in JavaScript, if a string is a proper regular expression that will compile?

For example, when you execute the following javascript, it produces an error.

```
var regex = new RegExp('abc ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+))');
// produces:
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /abc ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+))/: Unmatched ')'
```

How does one determine if a string will be a valid regex or not?

Comment: You need a regex to test a regex? lol

Comment: please specify your code clearly we will help you

Comment: yes, I have a text box that users enter a reg ex. so I want to validate user's reg ex. can you help me?

Comment: "validate" is too vague, do you want to validate specific regexes or all regexes?

Comment: what regex u going to validate design form and some code and post it here

Comment: all user's reg ex that entered in the my textbox

Comment: I want to check that the  input string is a valid regular exp or no

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you describe what you mean by "validate"?  Do you want to test whether it is a valid Perl-compatible regular expression, a valid ECMAScript regular expression, or simply check that it looks like one?  What about specific requirements, for example, would you consider a regular expression with backslashes where they aren't needed valid?   Will there be other input to this textbox or is there just meant to be regular expressions, and will they have to add slashes at the start and end of the regular expression?  Do users have the ability to specify flags?

Comment: Sorry, the comment was too long to fit into one.  Asking these types of questions to yourself and putting the answer to these types of things into your questions will dramatically improve the quality of your question - asking good questions will help the community answer your questions better and attract attention to your questions.  I;ve just listed _some_ of the specific types of things that you should add to your questions - there are other things as well.  Also, don't forget to try out a few things, do some basic research on the topic and describe your issue clearly.  Good luck! :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: thanks for your attention to my questions. as you have said I am beginner in this site and my English is a little weak.   my goal of this question is to define a special pattern to my inputs. in fact I have some text boxes and I want to allow users to type their favorite regular expression for them. as we create a regular expression in visual studio for asp controls.   by these descriptions I want a way to check user's regular expressions is correct or no?    did you know my goal?

Comment: Why is this 'not a real question' or 'closed' ? Or negative feedback? I found my answer here, with the exact problem as described !

Comment: Exactly.. unless it was edited, there's nothing vague about this question - valid expressions are those that will compile. Since we're talking about javascript here, it only makes sense to assume that this means ES expressions.

Comment: @FlorianMertens the question has been edited (quite a lot), you can vote for it to be re-opened as the question is now much better.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use `try/catch` and the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var isValid = true;
try {
    new RegExp("the_regex_to_test_goes_here");
} catch(e) {
    isValid = false;
}

if(!isValid) alert("Invalid regular expression");
```

Comment: @Jak: If you provide more information about what exactly "does not work" then we might be able to help you. But only saying "it does not work" gives us nothing. What input do you try? What output do you get? Are you getting a different error?

Comment: I replace my text box value instead of the_regex_to_test_goes_here       but it doesn't determine that the text box value is valid or no. is my question's information enough  now?

Comment: @JakSamun: Post a jsfiddle.com link with what you did, and tell us how the result was different than what you expected.

Comment: @Jon: I visited jsfiddle.com but I couldn't ask my question there. how can I do it?

Comment: thanks all of you, I find my answer by helping you.  thank you... thank you

Comment: @Jon for example this line `new RegExp('[AZ[a-z](a-z)','g')` doesn't throws an error, but the regular expression is incorrect, try in console. Try it in http://rubular.com/

Comment: It seems that implementation of JavaScript regular expressions differs from other languages. And pattern `'[AZ[a-z](a-z)'` in JS is the same as `'[AZ\[a-z](a-z)'`.

Comment: @DmitryDavydov that regex is indeed "correct" technically, although it's very confusing. Note that the behavior you cite is [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) (*The special characters ... shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression*).

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome 63 - seems to accept any value in the constructor without throwing.

Comment: @twoflower this is not possible, as I'm fairly certain Chrome still respects the spec; and [the spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-regexpinitialize) that `SyntaxError` must be thrown if the regex pattern is invalid... perhaps the pattern you used was correct after all?

Comment: @Jon You're right, my expression was not messed enough :-)

Comment: @p_champ the question is not about testing if a variable is a string or a regex. It's about testing if a given string would be syntactically valid as a regex.

Comment: @Jon oh yes, thanks for correcting me. deleted my comment.

Comment: That's the Pythonic way; _better forgiveness than approval._

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little function that checks the validity of both types of regexes, strings or patterns:

```
function validateRegex(pattern) {
    var parts = pattern.split('/'),
        regex = pattern,
        options = "";
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        regex = parts[1];
        options = parts[2];
    }
    try {
        new RegExp(regex, options);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The user will be able to test both `test` and `/test/g` for example. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmuzx/) is a working fiddle.

Comment: This functions allows any arbitrary strings in so I am not sure this does what op wants

Comment: (did you downvote? lol) My answer and the other answer basically do the exact same thing, with the exception that I also take into account possible options inside the pattern. And, to be honest, what OP wanted was just to "check if the input string is a valid regex or not"; there were no constraints on the input length specifically, so any string could be passed as input. Moreover, I'm doing exactly what he asked, even returning proper true or false value.

Comment: You don't account for a regex with a / as part of it.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here satisfied my need for checking that a string is a valid regex for other languages (Mostly php), because they either ignore the flags, the delimiters or escaped special characters, so I made my own function

```js
function isValidRegex(s) {
  try {
    const m = s.match(/^([/~@;%#'])(.*?)\1([gimsuy]*)$/);
    return m ? !!new RegExp(m[2],m[3])
        : false;
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
}

console.log(isValidRegex('abc')) //False
console.log(isValidRegex('/abc/')) //True
console.log(isValidRegex('/ab#\/[c]/ig')) //True
console.log(isValidRegex('@ab#\/[c]@ig')) //Special delimiters: True
console.log(isValidRegex('/ab\/[c/ig')) //False
console.log(isValidRegex('/abc/gig')) //False
```

You can also derive this function to transform a string into a RegExp object

```js
function stringToRegex(s) {
   const m = s.match(/^([/~@;%#'])(.*?)\1([gimsuy]*)$/);
   return m ? new RegExp(m[2], m[3]) : new RegExp(s);
}

console.log(stringToRegex('abc'))
console.log(stringToRegex('/abc/'))
console.log(stringToRegex('/ab#\/[c]/ig'))
console.log(stringToRegex('@ab#\/[c]@ig'))
try {
  console.log(stringToRegex('/ab#\/[c/ig'))
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Not a valid regex')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this function could handle the '/' char as a normal char in regex, and also consider escaping when is a common string. it will always return an Regex, null if not a good regex string.

```js
function getRegex(regex) {
    try {
        regex = regex.trim();
        let parts = regex.split('/');
        if(regex[0] !== '/' || parts.length< 3){
          regex = regex.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); //escap common string
          return new RegExp(regex);
        }

        const option =parts[parts.length - 1];
        const lastIndex = regex.lastIndexOf('/');
        regex = regex.substring(1, lastIndex);
        return new RegExp(regex, option);
    } catch (e) {
        return null
    }
}

console.log(getRegex('ab/c'))
let htmlStartTag = getRegex('/<(?!/)(?!br)(.+?)(?<!/)>/mgs');
console.log(htmlStartTag)
let result = `</button><input id="warehouse-search-field-tablet"
class="form-control search-field"
 title="Warehouse Search Field" name="location" type="search" value="">content`.matchAll(htmlStartTag);
 console.log([...result])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function isRegExp(regExp){
          try {
                new RegExp(regExp);
              } catch(e) {
                return false
              }
         return true
    }

ex:
isRegExp(/@(\w+)/g) = true
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to the code you posted? "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." -*[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*

Comment: i am just a beginner here, i'll improvise my answers with more understandable  explanation for given code. For this, all experimented code is offline, let me push all code on github and hit here back with reference link. Thank You #HappyCoding

Comment: this is more or less a duplicate of the original answer from 2013..

Answer (score -3):

The question is solved, but if someone needs to define is the string either valid *RegExp* or not a *RegExp* at all.

You can use `new Function()` and templating inside of the function body with `try ... catch` and `new RegExp()` as mentioned earlier.

There is a snippet with the explanations:

```js
const isRegExp = (string) => {
    try {
        return new Function(`
            "use strict";
            try {
                new RegExp(${string});
                return true;
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        `)();
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
};

// Here the argument 'simplyString' shall be undefined inside of the function
// Function(...) catches the error and returns false
console.log('Is RegExp valid:', isRegExp('simplyString'));

// Here the argument shall cause a syntax error
// isRegExp function catches the error and returns false
console.log('Is RegExp valid:', isRegExp('string which is not a valid regexp'));

// Here the argument is not a valid RegExp, new RegExp(...) throws an error
// Function(...) catches the error and returns false
console.log('Is RegExp valid:', isRegExp('abc ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+))'));

// Valid RegExp, passed as a string
console.log('Is RegExp valid:', isRegExp('/^[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]$/'));

// Valid RegExp, passed as a RegExp object
console.log('Is RegExp valid:', isRegExp(/^[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]$/));

// Howewer, the code injection is possible here
console.log('Is RegExp valid:', isRegExp(');console.log("This is running inside of the Function(...) as well"'));
```

Comment: Two upvotes on an answer with a code injection vulnerability.

Comment: an article on DailyWTF sufficiently points out the problem with this answer: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/evaluating-regexes